# Cglib proxy errors using and Spring Data when moving from Spring XD M5 to Release 1.0.0

Tags: spring-batch, spring-data-neo4j, spring-xd

We're moving a number of batch jobs from Spring XD M5 to the 1.0.0 release.

When creating and deploying the jobs, we are hitting an issue with cglib proxy functionality when autowiring Spring Data repositories (for Neo4J in this case).

The tail end of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasetRepository': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1512)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final
 class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:212)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:494)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:379)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:339)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
        at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:202)
        ... 68 more
```

The Spring Data repository interface is annotated with `@Repository` as follows:

```java
@Repository
public interface DatasetRepository extends GraphRepository<Dataset> 
{
    public Dataset findOneById(String id);
    public Dataset findOneByName(String name);
}
```

And the corresponding autowired attribute in our bean class which triggers the exception:

```java
    @Autowired
    private DatasetRepository datasetRepo;
```

The bean itself is defined in our XD job XML as follows:

```xml
<bean id="myBean" class="com.mycompany.MyBean"/>
```

And the configuration bean (component scanned in the job cfg XML):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories({ "com.mycompany.repositories" })
public class CustomNeo4jConfiguration implements InitializingBean
```

The versions of Spring Data Neo4J which we deploy into the XD lib folder are as follows:

```
spring-data-neo4j      : 3.2.0.RELEASE
spring-data-neo4j-rest : 3.2.0.RELEASE
```

The setup is all on a dev PC (for now) with XD running in distributed mode:

- redis server
- Zookeeper server (1x)
- Oracle job repository (local XE instance for now)
- 1x admin and 1x container

Any help around configuration of the job, Spring Data repository or XD container would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Update: Tried adding:

    `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false" />`

to the job XML but the same behaviour was observed.

Comment: Can you provide your Spring Batch configuration?  I'm working on a bug right now in Spring Batch (BATCH-2266) that has the same stack trace so I'm betting that's what it is but I want to confirm.

Comment: I am trying to reduce the application code to the bare minimum to re-produce the error but it's unfortunately taken a lower priority due to production activities. The batch config is that included in the Spring XD M5 release [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/1.0.0.M5/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-xd/batch/batch.xml)

Comment: I have fixed the issue previously mentioned (BATCH-2266).  Can you try packaging your job with the latest snapshots of Spring Batch (in the lib directory of your job module)?  By doing that, you'll override what Spring XD is providing.  That will help in diagnosis.

Comment: Will give it a go (probably next week based on priorities) - I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @Repository annotation on your GraphRepository and you should be fine. Don't forget to enable component scanning.